# Why is My Base 10 LSD Radix-Sort Faster Than My Bit-Shifted Radix Sort?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, binary, radix

So I was experimenting with different kinds of Radix sort for a school project where we have to sort 500,000 random integers (that I generate myself, with a bounds between 0 to MaxValue for each integer) as quickly as possible. I first made a base 10 LSD (Least Significant Digit) Radix sort that averages around 110 to 115ms for sorting 500,000 random integers. Here's the code for it:

```
public static int[] RadixSort(int[] RandomNumbers)
        {
            List<int>[] Buckets = new List<int>[10];

            int singleDigit = 0;
            int[] temp;
            int[] mult = new int[10] {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000};

            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
            {
                Buckets[0] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[1] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[2] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[3] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[4] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[5] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[6] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[7] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[8] = new List<int>();
                Buckets[9] = new List<int>();

                if (z == 0)
                {
                    temp = (int[])RandomNumbers.Clone();
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = (int[])RandomNumbers.Clone();

                    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    {
                        temp[i] /= (mult[z]);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                    singleDigit = temp[i] % 10;

                    Buckets[singleDigit].Add(RandomNumbers[i]);
                }

                List<int> NewList = new List<int>(SIZE);

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    NewList.AddRange(Buckets[i]);
                }

                int[] NewArray = NewList.ToArray();

                RandomNumbers = NewArray;
            }

            return RandomNumbers;
        }
```

However, I heard that using binary in a bit-shift Radix sort was faster. So I created a mask-based bit-shift Radix sort that overall looks less cluttered and has less operations going on within it, but its average sort speed is around 250ms. Here's the code for it:

```
public static int[] BitShiftRadixSort(int[] RandomNumbers)
        {
            List<int>[] Buckets = new List<int>[2];
            int binary;
            int mask;

            for (int shift = 0; shift < 32; shift++)
            {
                Buckets[0] = new List<int>(SIZE);
                Buckets[1] = new List<int>(SIZE);

                mask = 1 << shift;

                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                    binary = RandomNumbers[i] & mask;

                    if (binary != 0)
                    {
                        Buckets[1].Add(RandomNumbers[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Buckets[0].Add(RandomNumbers[i]);
                    }
                }

                List<int> NewList = new List<int>(SIZE);

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    NewList.AddRange(Buckets[i]);
                }

                int[] NewArray = NewList.ToArray();

                RandomNumbers = NewArray;
            }

            return RandomNumbers;
        }
```

I was expecting the bit-shift to be faster than the LSD Radix sort but that doesn't appear to be the case. Are mathematical operations in C# heavily optimized? I'll appreciate everyone's input!

Comment: It's because your outer loop requires 32 iterations instead of 10.

Comment: I thought this at first as well. But from my research, it should still be faster even though it has to iterate more times through. It has less buckets to sort into (only 2 instead of 10), and binary operations are supposed to be faster than mathematical. You could still very well be right though.

Comment: Usually you *would* use binary operations, but with a radix of 256 or so instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using Matt Timmermans suggestion of using base 256, this version for unsigned integers takes about 10ms for 500,000 32 bit unsigned integers. For signed integers, you would need to complement the sign bit and treat them as unsigned integers (then complement the sign back back).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace RadixSort
{
    class Program
    {

        static void RadixSort(uint [] a, uint count)
        {
        uint [,] mIndex = new uint [4,256];     // count / index matrix
        uint [] b = new uint [count];           // allocate temp array
        uint i,j,m,n;
        uint u;
            for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
                u = a[i];
                for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                    mIndex[j,(u & 0xff)]++;
                    u >>= 8;
                }       
            }
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
                m = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
                    n = mIndex[j,i];
                    mIndex[j,i] = m;
                    m += n;
                }       
            }
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // radix sort
                for(i = 0; i < count; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
                    u = a[i];
                    m = (u>>((int)(j<<3)))&0xff;
                    b[mIndex[j,m]++] = u;
                }
                uint [] t = a;                  //  swap references
                a = b;
                b = t;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int SIZE = 500000;
            uint [] a = new uint[SIZE];
            uint u;
            Random r = new Random(1);
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            for (uint i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                u = (uint)r.Next(1 << 16);
                u = (u << 16) | (uint)r.Next(1 << 16);
                a[i] = u;
            }
            sw.Start();
            RadixSort(a, (uint)a.Length);
            sw.Stop();
            for (uint i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if(a[i] < a[i-1])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("failed");
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("milliseconds: {0:D}\n",sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```